# Different ways of specifying properties inside object literals in javascript

Tags: javascript, properties, object-literal

I have seen the following two ways of specifying properties for an object literal in javascript..

```
var a = {prop:2}
```

and

```
var a ={'prop':2}
```

What is the difference between these two ways..I know that the second method allows us to include whitespaces inside the property names.Is there any other advantage.?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No difference other than your observation about the ability to create property names that are not valid identifiers. By using quoted strings for property names, any string can be used. When accessing such properties, of course, you later have to use `[ ]` instead of `.`:

```
var obj = { 'crazy property name': 100 };

if (obj[ 'crazy property name' ] > 1) alert("hi");
```

Note that strict JSON syntax *requires* that property names be quoted, and furthermore it *requires* that quoting always be done with double-quote characters.

Comment: Is JSON syntax equivalent to object literal syntax?

Comment: Its origin was object literal syntax (that's what the acronym stands for, after all), but its formal simplified "spec" requires double-quotes around property names, and JavaScript itself does not.

Comment: The answer seems to synonymize the two, although JSON syntax is not equivalent to object literal syntax. It's a valid point, I think, since it can be confusing to the uninitiated.